# Unix script to process data by comparing it to same key records

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, date

I have a problem in which Input file has Effective date and End date records. First 6 fields are the keys (12345A). We need to update End date(18 position) based on effective(8 position) date of the next record with same key - 1 day. For the records with newest effective date, 9999-12-31 should remain in End date. Below are the input and output expectations. Could someone please help me in this. I am fetching the file A as table unload and this has to be send later to interfacing application which is expected the end date to be populated like this, we can not change end date on table itself thats why we are trying to change it on unload file.

There is no data separator/delimiter and yes length of keys will always remain same.

Input (FILEA):

```
12345A22021-01-259999-12-31
12345A12021-01-019999-12-31
12345B32021-02-159999-12-31
67899C12021-03-019999-12-31
67899D32021-05-249999-12-31
67899D22021-04-029999-12-31
```

Output (FILEB):

```
12345A22021-01-259999-12-31
12345A12021-01-012021-01-24
12345B32021-02-159999-12-31
67899C12021-03-019999-12-31
67899D32021-05-249999-12-31
67899D22021-04-022021-05-23
```

Comment: Why `2021-01-24` in line 2, while line 1 has `2021-01-25` as effective date? Same for line 6 (`05-23` instead of `05-24`)? Otherwise something like `sed -E 'N;s/^(.{6})(.)(.{10})(.*\n\1.{11}).*/\1\2\3\4\3/;P;D' fileA > fileB` would do the trick.

Comment: (1) As Philippos says, if you have a requirement to subtract one from the previous value, you should say so. (2) Is there a requirement to compare the effective dates on consecutive lines, or just the keys? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Philippos - yes, the end date should be newest record efective date - 1 day

Comment: @Philippos -  I ran your command, its giving this error - sed: Not a recognized flag: E

Comment: This means your `sed` version is quite old and does not support extended regular expressions. You can use standard regular expressions by adding a couple of backslashes: `sed 'N;s/^\(.\{6\}\)\(.\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\n\1.\{11\}\).*/\1\2\3\4\3/;P;D' fileA > fileB`, but you still need to decrement the date …

Comment: @Philippos - Its not copying the last line - 67899D22021-04-022021-05-23 in output file . 
 thanks for the help, its working fine except the minus one, will find something more on that.

Comment: Maybe your `sed` version needs to start with `$!N;`, not sure about that. I offered an answer for the minus-1 task, but it will require you to install at least GNU `sed`.

Comment: added !N, but it didnt work. output came as same as input file with all the records

Answer (score 0):

As long as the effective date of the preceding record with same ID shall be taken as end date, you can do it with standard `sed` and the `N;P;D` pattern like this:

```
sed '$!N;s/^\(.\{6\}\)\(.\)\(.\{10\}\)\(.*\n\1.\{11\}\).*/\1\2\3\4\3/;P;D'
```

But as soon as you need to change the date, you need a utility that understands a calendar like GNU `date`:

```
date -d "2021-09-08 yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

will output `2021-09-07`. I doubt many versions of `date` will do the trick that way. But with a current GNU `date` and GNU `sed`, this should work:

```
sed -nE 'G
  s/^(.{6})(.{11}).*\n\1.(.{10}).*/\1\2\3/p
  s/\n.*//p
  s/^(.{7})(.{10})/echo \1$(date -d "\2 yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")/e
  h' fileA > fileB
```

Let me try to explain:

- We use option `n` to suppress default output and option `E` for extended regular expressions (just for readability)
- `G` appends the hold space, where we are going to keep the previous line with adapted date (see below)
- `s/^(.{6})(.{11}).*\n\1.(.{10})/\1\2\3/p` replaces the date of the current line with the adapted date from hold space, only if it has the same ID (thus the backreference `\1`) and `p`rints it
- `s/\n.*//p` simply removes the appended line if no replacement did take place and `p`rints it
- `s/^(.{7})(.{10})/echo \1$(date -d "\2 yesterday" +"%Y-%m-%d")/e` make use of GNU `sed`'s `e`xecute flag to send the date to `date` utility to decrement it
- `h` saves this changed line to hold space

Comment: sed: Not a recognized flag: E
I believe, we are using a really old version.  Unfortunately, we cant update it as its going to migration in coming months to Azure.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Does the `date` command work for you? Then we'll find another solution without `sed